# Execute downloading file before dowload ends

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to make Google-Chrome execute the .crdownload file when clicking on a file in the download bar instead of opening the file when the download ends?

I often open with VLC the .crdownload file of a video I'm downloading so I can watch the video while downloading and I'm tired of having to open the file explorer to access it.

Comment: The .crdownload file is a temporary file that any kind of download in Chrome is written to.  When the download is complete, the file is renamed with the appropriate extension.  It isn't intended as a way to stream content, so if you can open an incomplete video download with VLC, that's pretty neat, but probably an exception.

Comment: Short answer, No.

Comment: Can you not use a symlink (http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/13085/windows-7-how-to-create-symlinks-symbolic-links/) to the file - with a name other then the final name, but appropriate extension -  to do this ?